# method is returning id but not saving other data points

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, asynchronous, mongoose

My method works when I put values in new Farm () but not when I run it through postman in JSON which is also displayed below. I do not think I am parsing the JSON incorrectly. Any suggestions would be appreciated ?

```
export interface IDataFlowService {
handle(request: IDataFlowRequest): Promise<IDataFlowResponse>;

}

export class DataFlowService implements IDataFlowService {

current_env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

 async handle(request: IDataFlowRequest): Promise<IDataFlowResponse> {

    let response: IDataFlowResponse;

    try {


        switch (request.requestType) {
            case "SaveFarms":
                response = await this.SaveFarms(request);
                break;

                default:
                winston.error(`Request failed for request type: ${request.requestType}`);

                break;
        }
        return response;

    } catch (e) {
        winston.error(`handle method failed for request: ${request}`, e);

        response = {
            success: false,
            error: {
                'message': e.message,
            }
        };
        return response;
    }
}

private async SaveFarms(request: IDataFlowRequest): Promise<IDataFlowResponse> {

    const response: IDataFlowResponse = {
        success: true ,
        farmIds: [],
        names: []
       };

for (const farm of request.farms) {

const newFarm: IFarmModel = new Farm();

Promise.all([newFarm.save()]);
response.farmIds.push(newFarm.farmId) ;
response.names.push(newFarm.name) ;

       }


        return response;
    }
}
```

here is post: http://localhost:5000/api/dataflow

```
{
"requestType":"SaveFarms",
"farms": [

  {
  "name" : "Bronx"

   }

   ]
   }
```

as you can see I get a response but the names field is coming back null/empty:

```
{
"success": true,
"farmIds": [
    "fH1WjllXR"
],
"names": [
    null
]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget set `name` for `newFarm` object:

```
const newFarm: IFarmModel = new Farm();
newFarm.name = farm.name; // I think so
```